# cannot read pdf on windows store apps with component one pdf reader

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-store-apps, componentone

I want to create an application that can read pdf on windows store. The pdf can be obtained by downloading it from the server and can be accessed via the application. There are 2 types of pdf with 2 different passwords. The free pdf using the password "East" and the paid pdf using the password "Java". I have a problem, the paid pdf can not read and just empty, but the free pdf that can be read.

Here is my code for read the pdf, after download its from server:

```
async private void LoadFile(string name)
        {

            StorageFolder installedLocation = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFolder koleksibuku = await installedLocation.CreateFolderAsync("library", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await koleksibuku.GetFilesAsync();
            StorageFolder thumbfolder = await installedLocation.CreateFolderAsync("thumb", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            foreach (StorageFile file in files)
            {
                if (file.DisplayName == name)
                {
                    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                    Stream fileStream = stream.AsStreamForRead();

                    try
                    {
                        //free = false;
                        string password = "East";
                        pdfViewer.LoadDocument(fileStream, password);                        
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //free = true;
                        string password = "Java";
                        pdfViewer.LoadDocument(fileStream, password);                    
                    }
}
```

Please help me....

Comment: is there any difference in the pdf files? what happens if you open the links in a browser? then it just works? what makes it a free/paid pdf?

Comment: The differences is the password. It must open on pdf viewer with component one pdf viewer.

Comment: I mean there is that there are two types of PDF, such as a pdf and pdf b. If the pdf A then use the password "East" and pdf b using the password "Java". The problem is if pdfViewer.LoadDocument (FileStream, "East"); I put in try {}, then the pdf b can not be read, however if I put pdfViewer.LoadDocument (FileStream, "East"); in catch {} then a pdf that can not be read.

Please help me